# How to update entity model (EF 5) programmatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We got a C#-application made with VS2015 in which we use entity framework (EF 5 with data first).

In the model we must adjust a column in some of the included entities from the database to StoreGeneratedPattern = Computed.

In our case we got in these entities a column of type datetime in which we want in case of insert the current timestamp (as it is defined in the database) without setting it explicitly in the code.

This can be achieved in the EDMX designer by setting the pattern manually.

But because we update the model from time to time by removing changed entities and re-adding them by "Update model from the database" the pattern setting would be lost and must be re-added.

Because this is dangerous if a developer forget to adjust one of the entity columns we wanted to adjust this in the model by code.

So we tried this in the constructor of the entity model:

```
public MyEntity()
    : base("name=MyEntity")
{
    DbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Table_A>().Property(t => t.column1)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
}
```

Each time an instance of the entity model is created the code is executed.
But - instead of working as the pattern was adjusted manually - the current timestamp is not set in the database after insert.

How can we solve that problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated class will always be a partial class. This allows you to write a second partial class which is marked with the necessary modifications
in your case you cand create an other partial class that will contain the your modification 
after update Edmx , the created partial class will not be regenerated

Comment: Hello Alaaeddine. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Can that second partial class have the same classname as the entity?

Comment: yes of course, we use Partial classes to split one class to many partial class.https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods